# How to write Drool rules in Excel sheet?

Tags: drools

Can we write Drool rules in Excel sheet?
Can rules be used for simple human readable content?
If we can then how it can be done?
Please explain.

Comment: What are "drool rules"?

Comment: What basically drools is you have from here: http://www.jboss.org/drools/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. How about reading the section of the user guide called "Decision Tables in Spreadsheets"?

http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html_single/#d0e1157

Comment: Link to latest version: https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/drools/language-reference/index.html#decision-tables-con_decision-tables

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write rules in Spread Sheet Xls and after uploading those rules will automatically convert to drl.
If you have lots of similar rules with different values you can make use of Drools Decision Tables.
You can define the decision tables in an Excel spreadsheet (the .xls file).

I am attaching simple rule file that may help you
In this example we are deciding rate according to Age of renter, Time(Duration of loan), and the sex.

**Data Model:**

```
package demopro.demopro;

/**
 * This class was automatically generated by the data modeler tool.
 */

public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable
{

   static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private java.lang.Integer time;
   private java.lang.Integer age;
   private java.lang.Integer interest;
   private java.lang.String gender;
   private java.lang.Integer rate;
   private java.lang.Integer amount;

   public Customer()
   {
   }

   public java.lang.Integer getTime()
   {
      return this.time;
   }

   public void setTime(java.lang.Integer time)
   {
      this.time = time;
   }

   public java.lang.Integer getAge()
   {
      return this.age;
   }

   public void setAge(java.lang.Integer age)
   {
      this.age = age;
   }

   public java.lang.Integer getInterest()
   {
      return this.interest;
   }

   public void setInterest(java.lang.Integer interest)
   {
      this.interest = interest;
   }

   public java.lang.String getGender()
   {
      return this.gender;
   }

   public void setGender(java.lang.String gender)
   {
      this.gender = gender;
   }

   public java.lang.Integer getRate()
   {
      return this.rate;
   }

   public void setRate(java.lang.Integer rate)
   {
      this.rate = rate;
   }

   public java.lang.Integer getAmount()
   {
      return this.amount;
   }

   public void setAmount(java.lang.Integer amount)
   {
      this.amount = amount;
   }

   public Customer(java.lang.Integer time, java.lang.Integer age,
         java.lang.Integer interest, java.lang.String gender,
         java.lang.Integer rate, java.lang.Integer amount)
   {
      this.time = time;
      this.age = age;
      this.interest = interest;
      this.gender = gender;
      this.rate = rate;
      this.amount = amount;
   }    
}
```

**Decision Table(SpreadSheet):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is better to start with sample rules excel generated using Eclipse Drools Plugin. It gives many things already set up. Just change the data inside and use decision tables excel for your program. In this [Drools Decision Table Tutorial](http://www.deepakgaikwad.net/index.php/2016/05/23/drools-decision-table-tutorial-beginners-using-drools-6-4.html), same method is used for Drools 6.4

Comment: Warning, the tutorial link above is dead as of 2024, redirects to an irrelevant site.