# Drools : drl file variables

Tags: java, drools, drools-guvnor, drools-fusion

Below is my class :

```
    public class NumberDetails {

        private String a ; 
        private String b;
        private String c;
        private String status;

        private String result;

         // getters and setters
        }
```

Initilize values 
status : 302, a = "A", b="2"

I have to apply logic :

```
if(status=302){
    result = a+b; 

}
```

How to write this in .drl file ?

```
rule "302 case"
when 
    numberObject: NumberDetails(status==302)
then

    numberObject.setResult(numberObject(a)+numberObject(b)); // I know this is wrong but how to write it ?
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getter and setter` methods to get the value in your `drl file`. For example, you can write your rule as:

```
rule "302 case"
when 
    numberObject: NumberDetails(status==302)
then

    numberObject.setResult(numberObject.getA()+numberObject.getB());
end
```

Comment: Ok Thanks. 
if I have to take this numberObject.getA() and numberObject.getB() in a String then how to do it. 
then
    strA = numberObject.getA();
    strB = numberObject.getB();
    numberObject.setResult(strA+strB);
end

Comment: @VJS The datatype of A and B is already a string. If you want to concatenate the value u can directly use `+` operator.

Comment: I understand this. But still, I want to know the syntax. How to do it.

Comment: @VJS `then` part of my answer will set the result value as `A+B`. If you want to get the value of result variable then u can use `numberObject.getResult()`

Comment: If i want to write rules in excel instead of drl file, can you please help me in this ?

Comment: You can get the detail on how to write rules in Excel on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995147/how-to-write-drool-rules-in-excel-sheet